# Could those comments be moved to chat, and is this the right way to ask it?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

[My answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/415781/6605) got a substantial amount of comments. The user commenting the most suggested recently to continue the discussion in chat, and this is indeed a great idea.

1. Would it be possible to move the comments to chat?
2. Am I doing it right to ask that on Meta? Or is there a different mechanism for me (either as an author of the question, or as a high rep user) to do it myself?
3. I couldn't find the exact criteria which would make the “move comments discussion to chat” link appear. [One answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3517/466295) on a different Meta says that it is displayed when the conversation “grows long enough,” but the exact rules of what's long or short don't seem clear. Shouldn't the conversation from my answer be considered *long enough*?
4. Last but not least, would the other participants be somehow informed that the conversation moved to chat? I don't remember seeing such notification, but at the same time, I don't remember my conversations being moved to chat either.